# Code listings: shaded background

Tags: color, verbatim

How do I make sure that my verbatim text output examples have a shaded gray background?

```
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{color}
....
{\small\begin{alltt}
\# mycommand install
\# mycommand configure
\# mycommand exit
\end{alltt}}
```

Using a color box seems like overkill for a simple bgcolor change such as this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can mark up code as such in the question by highlighting it and clicking on the `{}` button or by indenting it by four spaces.

Answer (score 2):

`tcolorbox` could be one option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!30]
{\small\begin{alltt}
\# mycommand install
\# mycommand configure
\# mycommand exit
\end{alltt}}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can nest the `alltt` environment in a simple `shaded` or `shaded*` environment, from the `framed` package. Note it can break across pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Gainsboro!50}
\usepackage{alltt} %
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{shaded}\small
\begin{alltt}
\# mycommand install
\# mycommand configure
\# mycommand exit
\end{alltt}
\end{shaded}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{shaded*}\small
\begin{alltt}
\# mycommand install
\# mycommand configure
\# mycommand exit
\end{alltt}
\end{shaded*}

\end{document}
```

[image]