# Fira code breaks listings background

Tags: fonts, xetex, listings, code, backgrounds

I'm trying to use Fira Code on listings with a background. However, the background lines break above `(`, `)`, `{` and `}`. At first I thought this was a problem with custom fonts in general, but after testing with a random monospaced font I have in my system (LiberationMono-Regular), it seems to work fine. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, listings, caption, xcolor, tcolorbox}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}\bfseries}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelformat=simple,format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Useful Code (Regular)]
// Some very useful code
// It truly does some amazing stuff
for (int i = 0; i <= matrix->width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix->height; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\setmonofont{LiberationMono-Regular.ttf}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Useful Code (Liberation)]
// Some very useful code
// It truly does some amazing stuff
for (int i = 0; i <= matrix->width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix->height; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\setmonofont{Fira Code Regular}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Useful Code (Fira Code)]
// Some very useful code
// It truly does some amazing stuff
for (int i = 0; i <= matrix->width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix->height; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note: In this example I'm using a caption design developed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742069/14656198). This is an important detail, since it means that [simple solutions with tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441844/228525) won't suffice, as it also wraps around the caption, breaking the look that this design aims for.*

Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Using `tcblisting` is certainly the best approach. You just need to declare the caption with some approach, e.g. `\captionof` command.

Comment: Fira is larger,  you should adapt the line spacing.  But using tcolorbox is certainly recommended. It has all the means to create your layout.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer @AlanXiang Feel free to post an answer. I have nothing against the use of `tcolorbox`, it just happens that most solutions that I've seen using it don't go well with this design, and I don't have the knowledge to adapt it. However, if you know how to, feel free to leave your take using `tcolorbox` or `tcblistings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clearly see that parentheses and braces are doing that. The reason is that they are quite higher than the corresponding characters in the standard font.

You have a couple of choices available.

#### 1. Increase the leading inside listings

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, listings, caption, xcolor, tcolorbox}

\setmonofont{Fira Code Regular}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}\bfseries}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \colorbox{gray}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}%
  }%
}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  labelformat=simple,
  format=listing,
  labelfont=white,
  textfont=white
}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{1.1}\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9},
}

\begin{document}

Text \texttt{Text} \{x\}\texttt{\{x\}}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Useful Code (Regular)]
// Some very useful code
// It truly does some amazing stuff
for (int i = 0; i <= matrix->width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix->height; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### 2. Reduce the size of the font

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, listings, caption, xcolor, tcolorbox}

\setmonofont{Fira Code Regular}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}\bfseries}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{%
  \colorbox{gray}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}%
  }%
}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  labelformat=simple,
  format=listing,
  labelfont=white,
  textfont=white
}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9},
}

\begin{document}

Text \texttt{Text} \{x\}\texttt{\{x\}}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Useful Code (Regular)]
// Some very useful code
// It truly does some amazing stuff
for (int i = 0; i <= matrix->width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix->height; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `Scale=0.9`

[image]